# Clang can't find system headers without --stdlib=libc++

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, clang

On my system (Ubuntu 22.04) I have a problem where clang doesn't find system headers but gcc does. I have a simple test program...

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "hello world!" << endl;
}
```

I can compile this just fine with `g++ main.cpp -o test` but `clang++ main.cpp -o test` will fail with...

```
main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Output of `clang++ -E -xc++ - -v -std=c++17 --stdlib=libc++`:

```
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 (in-process)
 "/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -E -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/david -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/../include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/david -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o - -x c++ -
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 based upon LLVM 14.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
^C
```

Output of `clang++ -E -xc++ - -v -std=c++17`

```
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 (in-process)
 "/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -E -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/david -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/david -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o - -x c++ -
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 based upon LLVM 14.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
^C
```

if I use `clang++ main.cpp -o test --stdlib=libc++` it will work fine, shouldn't this be the default though? How can I configure clang to find the header without having to pass that argument?

Comment: The default C++ standard library on Ubuntu Clang is libstdc++, not libc++. It's weird though, I have the same Ubuntu version and same Clang version, and it does work without any extra flags. I get different output: https://pastebin.com/J3Ab1Db2

Comment: Does it work for you on a clean OS install? What does `g++ --version` say? Also, you're mixing `clang++` and `clang` in your question, which one do you use? I get a different error from the latter, but still.

Comment: going to try a clean install in a virtualbox, also i reran with clang++ instead of clang and updated the output. not sure if there was any change though

Comment: after installing in virtualbox and running the same command, I have more paths...
 `/usr/include/c++/11` and `/usr/includex86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11`

Comment: But does it work? And did you install `g++` on the virtualbox?

Comment: it does work on virtualbox, not sure why it has the extra paths though. or how to configure those paths on my host

Comment: the path `/usr/include/c++/11` has the files i need on the host. not sure why clang isn't searching those directories or how to fix that though.

Comment: i think i found the problem. having the package `gcc-12` installed caused clang to use the wrong gcc installation

Comment: This answer suggests (and helped me) to actually install `g++-12`: https://askubuntu.com/a/1441954/142834

Comment: I have both `gcc-12` and `g++-12`. I would install those to give Clang a newer C++ standard library.